# calling ajax every 10 seconds using setinterval

Tags: ajax, server

i'm using setinterval to call ajax every 10 seconds so my question is,is this way are bad for server,does using setinterval make ajax effect badly on server side and if it's what is the best way to do that without effect badly on server side,thanks

Comment: Please be specific with your requirement as what technology stack are you using what is the task that you are performing is it clock sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means an XHR Request every 10 seconds to the server, which is not a bad practice, since it is a core requirement. However, there can be a solution to it by applying the mechanism of **Caching Data** on **Server Side**, to reduce direct hits to the Database, and only perform hits in case there are any [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) Operations applied on Database.